# Webview not working with iOS9

Tags: ios, swift, webview, ios9

I had created app which is not working with iOS 9.

```
import UIKit

    class WebViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

        @IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!
        override func viewDidLoad()
        {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

            let requestURL = NSURL(string:"http://stackoverflow.com")
            let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
            webView.loadRequest(request)

            webView.delegate = self

        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

        func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView)
        {
            print("Load started")
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
        }
        func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView)
        {
            print("Load finished")
            UIApplication .sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false

        }
        func webView(webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: NSError?)
        {
            print("Error = ", error)
        }
        func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool
        {
            print("URl ", request.URL?.absoluteString)
            return true
        }
    }
```

Showing this message.

> 2015-10-20 14:46:29.976 WebViewDemo[2802:84627] Loading URL
>   :https://stackoverflow.com/ 2015-10-20 14:46:30.041
>   WebViewDemo[2802:84745] App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext
>   HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary
>   exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.
>   2015-10-20 14:46:30.160 WebViewDemo[2802:84627] Failed to load with
>   error :Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1022 "The resource could
>   not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the
>   use of a secure connection."
>   UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fedabe113b0 {Error
>   Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1022 "The resource could not be
>   loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a
>   secure connection."
>   UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://stackoverflow.com/,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The resource could not be loaded because the
>   App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure
>   connection., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://stackoverflow.com/}},
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://stackoverflow.com/,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://stackoverflow.com/,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The resource could not be loaded because the
>   App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure
>   connection.}

Comment: In IOS 9 Nd Later we need to add NSAppTransportSecurity in Info.Plist
Open Info.Plist As source code and copy and paste this at the end.

<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>

Comment: I wouldn't say this *needs* to be done. Ideally you should try and use secure connections where possible. i.e. HTTPS rather than HTTP.

Comment: Also is the same code that caused this error? Because the error is throwing up an error loading Stack Overflow, not Google as in your code. So for this example (based on your error) use `https://stackoverflow.com` since Stack Overflow does support HTTPS connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add this in your `.plist` file

1. Add a `NSAppTransportSecurity` : Dictionary.
2. Add Subkey named :  **NSAllowsArbitraryLoads**  as `Boolean` : YES

[image]

Hopefully this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Set the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads key to YES under NSAppTransportSecurity dictionary in your .plist file. If NSAppTransportSecurity not exist manually write it.

[image]